# Talend 6.1.1 osgi bundle with Fuse Integration issue

Tags: osgi, talend, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi

I am trying to deploy Talend 6.1.1 osgi bundle jar in Fuse server. During build execution, Talend routines jars are not getting resolved and facing the wiring exceptions.  Below is my features and the fuse error log. 
Any suggestion?

```
<feature name="test-xxx" version="1.0.0">    
    <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.talend.testloader.testloader_xml/testloader_xml-bundle/0.1</bundle>    
</feature>    


ERROR | 6.0.1-1-thread-1 | DeploymentAgent                  | 86 - io.fabric8.fabric-agent - 1.2.0.redhat-621084 | Unable to update agent
org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=test-xxx-feature; type=karaf.feature; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=test-xxx-feature)(type=karaf.feature))" [caused by: Unable to resolve test-xxx-feature/1.0.0: missing requirement [test-xxx-feature/1.0.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=test-xxx; type=karaf.feature [caused by: Unable to resolve test-xxx/1.0.0: missing requirement [test-xxx/1.0.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.talend.testloader.testloader_xml; type=osgi.bundle; version="[0.1.0,0.1.0]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve org.talend.testloader.testloader_xml/0.1.0: missing requirement [org.talend.testloader.testloader_xml/0.1.0] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=routines.system.api)"]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install all necessary features and configs from Talend ESB into Fuse. Theoretically this is possible as both run on Apache Karaf but it is a lot of work and I am pretty sure you will not get support from Fuse or Talend.

The error above tells you that the package `routines.system.api` is missing.

```
karaf@trun()> exports | grep routines.system.api
routines.system.api                                                                                    | 6.1.1            | 222 | org.talend.esb.job.api
```

You can use the above command in TESB to check which bundle provides the package and add the respective bundle.

If you do this until you have no such errors anymore then at least the bundle should resolve... but this does not mean it actually will work.

Comment: Below are the actions has been taken:-
1) Added Talend 6 supportive jars as bundles in fuse.

advancedPersistentLookupLib-1.0, antlr-runtime-3.5.2, filecopy, ini4j-0.5.1, jaxen-1.1.1, jboss-serialization, log4j-1.2.15, log4j-1.2.16, ojdbc6
org.talend.dataquality.parser, org-apache-commons-codec, pw-swift-core-7.0-2012, talend_file_enhanced_20070724, talendcsv, talend-oracle-timestamptz, TalendSAX, tns, trove

2) Exported by Talend job along with Routines supportives as osgi bundle

3) Deployed the above in fuse

post which getting the errors which i mentioned in my question.

Comment: **Thanks, **
Correction in my previous chat and below is the step i am doing it for this deployment.

1) Create a test Talend job

2) export as a Fuse project with inclusion of supportive jars, routines, context files.

3) Deployed that bundle in to Fuse container.

As suggested, put grep "exports | grep routines" in fuse and nothing got listed out. 
Since I have bundled routines also with my Talend job, this cannot be done i guess.

Please correct me if understand is wrong.
Also suggest me if any good approach would be there.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fixing this issue, 
we need to add routines package as first import in the < bundle.config.export.package > tag in your Talend job POM.xml.

This will make sure your routines packages are getting deployed/resolved prior than your developed Talend jobs in the container.

```
<bundle.config.export.package>routines.system.api,testloaders.test_XML_0_1;uses:="javax.sql,routines.system,routines.system.api"</bundle.config.export.package>
```